# Want to predict sale quantity by product department from user input via webpage flask

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have applied One Hot Encoding and then decision trees and got a good score for my department and quantity column.

When I do :

```
prediction = dt_clf.predict([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
print(prediction)
```

I get the following output :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Beef'
```

But i want to convert it to pickle and deploy it to python flask and so the user can give an input and retrieve the prediction.

Do i have to do one hot encoding again if so please correct this piece of code for me :

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)

# Train a decision tree regression model with the best hyperparameters found by grid search
dt_clf = DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='friedman_mse', splitter='random')
dt_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluate the model on the test set
dt_score = dt_clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Decision Tree Regression Test Score:", dt_score)`
```

I want the user to give their input to predict via a webpage. Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the data format is consistent across training, evaluating, and testing. For one-hot-encoding, you will want to `fit_transform()` the encoder on the training set, and then only call `transform()` on the test.

See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) for the official docs. You will need to decide how to handle unknowns (i.e., if the test set contains labels that are not seen in the training set). An simple example adapted from the docs:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = "ignore")
x_train = encoder.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = encoder.transform(x_test)
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for your reply, I am actually new learning python. if i share you my csv file as well code and if u can correct it i can learn. if u have time to do so. thanks again

Comment: Hi abc777, please remember this site is for questioning and answering, if you want to learn please check respective subject books or other material.

Comment: @mouse, i have used the code you have given. I have department, monthincalendar, and store_code these three features in X axis and net_amt is my y axis. under department I have beef, mutton, poultry....  under monthincalendar  i have 22-Dec, 220Nov, 22-Oct... and under store_code i have GB, dark, warehouse ... when i use your given encoding its worked but as a user i have to give all beef, mutton, poultry, 22-Dec, 220Nov, 22-Oct, GB, dark, warehouse as features to get the y value. what i want is i type as user beef, 22-Dec, warehouse as X- asix and get the Net_amount of y-axis

Comment: or mutton, 23-Jan, Dark_store and get get the Net_amount of y-axis. please help me how can i resolve

Comment: i have the solution. thanks guys